# How can i integrate css/js from a HTML template into a laravel application?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5

Im importing a HTML template into my laravel application. i copied all the css/js files in their respective folders in the public directory. i did not change the the style links from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/animate.css') }}"/>
```

as it was working just fine. However, for the show function , which takes a parameter, in my ShopController , the css is not applied. If i remove the parameter '$id' in show function  and route, it works fine again. I donot understand why the css is applied to all the routes where no data is passed but fails for routes with passed data. Here is my route for products page

```
Route::get('/shop/{product}', 'ShopController@show')->name('shop.show');
```

ShopController:

```
 public function show($id)
{
    return view('product');
}
```

the view file

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code of the product view file

Comment: When your css is not implemented open source code and check the link for the css is it ok or not?

Comment: @MuhammadTalha i edited the question to include my view file.  I checked the source code in both cases. Its the same.

Comment: When ever you use link use helper url('css/style.css')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if there is something in the route then it tries to get it like this: http://localhost/routedata/css/style.css

You have to do it like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}"/>
```